# How to make the keyboard show emoji in the word prediction area?

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard, emoji

On iPhone 7, when I type an emoji's name, it would show up in the word prediction bar above the keyboard.

On iPhone 12, this doesn't happen by default. How can I force it to happen? It's so useful and convenient to not have to 1. Open the emoji keyboard 2. Click its search bar 3. Search the emoji name 4. Tap the emoji 5. Tap the emoji button 6. Tap the ABC button.

[image: screenshot of what I mean. Sunglasses is typed in the normal keyboard, and the emoji is available as a button in the text prediction bar.]

Comment: Could you update the question with the app are you using here?

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 16 (the highest I go to..) this is controlled for the standard keyboard in Settings | General | Keyboards | All Keyboards | Predictive.

Now I'm assuming you do have that switched on, it would be the first thing to check, but I found an [Apple forum conversation](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250689867) where it was stated that you have to use the prediction for a word a minimum 5 times before it starts showing emoji. Can't vouch to the veracity of that.

Another thing I've found in testing is that emoji prediction only seems to be a feature for keyboards used in messaging apps (or unless otherwise used by an app developer). I can only seem to see it in Messages, Discord, DayOne, Twitter and WhatsApp (the ones I use).

Comment: Do you know how to force emoji prediction to be active in all apps? I've just noticed it doesn't work in Notes, so weird